# 'Rolling up' records in triplicate, nested case statement (or loops)

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms-2012

I have a table with four columns: ID, OUTPUT, NOTE_TEXT, SOURCE

The ID values are in triplicate since I pulled the date from three different SOURCEs with a union all (a union won't work, which sucks). Effectively triplicating each record.

I need to roll these triplicate ID values up into one record per ID.

Below is a screenshot of the four variations of data for NOTE_TEXT values per ID triplicates:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxUee.png)

Here's an example output from the query below:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkvCP.png)

As is evident from ID = 00793, the below case statement didn't work. Why is that? As well, can it be modified to work, or should I build a series of loops, or is there an even more elegant solution?

The end goal is to save this as a stored procedure and call into an SSIS project. Any insight or advice is appreciated.

```
select * from 
(
select 
ID
,OUTPUT
,case
    when NOTE_TEXT = '' then case
                                 when [SOURCE] = 'G1' and NOTE_TEXT != '' then NOTE_TEXT
                                 when [SOURCE] = 'G2' and NOTE_TEXT != '' then NOTE_TEXT
                                 when [SOURCE] = 'ENG' and NOTE_TEXT != '' then NOTE_TEXT
                                 else ''
                                 end
    else NOTE_TEXT
    end as NOTE_TEXT
from Table
) as temp
group by ID, OUTPUT, NOTE_TEXT
```

Edit: I may have been unclear, this is the logic I'd like to build into the query, using the existing case statement or any other way.

- If all three ID records have NULL in the NOTE_TEXT column, use one (or the first) ID record with NULL for NOTE_TEXT
- If all three ID records have the same text in the NOTE_TEXT column, use one (or the first) ID record with the text in NOTE_TEXT
- If, in the three ID records, the NOTE_TEXT column has one text value and the rest are NULL, use one (or the first) ID record and the text in NOTE_TEXT
- If, in the three ID records, the NOTE_TEXT column has multiple text values, use the the first ID record and NOTE_TEXT for a single record.

Comment: what's the desired result here?

Comment: Tips: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: When `Note_Text` is empty and _not_ empty and `Source` has some particular value then return the empty string? Otherwise an empty string or just keep the original value? Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu "I need to roll these triplicate ID values up into one record per ID." With the union all, I have ~2500 records, three records per ID. I need ~830 records, one record per ID. I've included an edit with logic

Comment: @HABO, Good comments, sorry if I've been unclear. I'm connecting to a 2016 sql server in SSMS 2012. Not sure I follow your questions in your second comment. I've edited to the question to include a clearer understanding of the logic I'd like to build in.

Comment: reckon this is just a easy job but not seeing the desired output will cost us too much thinking and end up not helping you. so good luck

Comment: @maSTAShuFu if it's not clear from the screenshots, should I just 'write' the columns headers and records into the question?

Comment: `when NOTE_TEXT = '' then ... when [SOURCE] = 'G1' and NOTE_TEXT != '' then NOTE_TEXT` says what? When the note text _is_ empty and the source is "G1" and the note text _isn't_ empty then use the (not)empty note text. That isn't going to work well for anyone other than Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: Haha, @HABO perfect, thanks for confirming. I thought that was the behaviour there but I wasn't sure. I decided not to use case statements in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using case statements wasn't going to work, based on the @Habo's comment. Instead, this worked.

```
select distinct(ID) AS ID
,'' AS OUTPUT_TYPE
,       (
       select top 1
           NOTE_TEXT
       from [table] AS t
       where NOTE_TEXT is not null
             and NOTE_TEXT != ''
             and t.SUPPLIER_ID = s.SUPPLIER_ID
   ) as NOTE_TEXT
from [table] as s
```